# MYSQL query with REGEXP - make-it non greedy

Tags: mysql, regex

I need some help with a regular expression for a MYSQL query to search rows with which contain a cell with an exact pattern. I'm new on MYSQL regex.

This is a sample table named as test_table (json_value is a json string of an array)

```
|id |    json_value                                                                                 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | {"field_198":false,"field_4":"From quality office","field_9":"product with high quality","field_10":"comment"}    
| 2 | {"field_198":true,"field_4":"From ordering office","field_9":"back to quality office","field_10":"comment"}   
| 3 | {"field_198":true,"field_4":"From ordering office","field_9":"cancelled","field_10":"comment"}                    
| 4 | {"field_198":true,"field_4":"Return to quality office","field_9":"product ok","field_10":"comment"}
```

If I want to get all rows with :

```
- field_4 containing "quality" string, the query should to return id 1 and 4
- field_9 containing "quality" string, the query should to return id 1 and 2
- field_4 containing "ordering" string, the query should to return id 2 and 3
```

I hope the example is concludent.

I have tried use this query

```
SELECT id from test_table WHERE json_value REGEXP 'field_4":".*quality.*';
```

but return id 1, 2 and 4 because is greedy and find the "quality" at field_9 from row 2

Another query is (I know, this is a stupid regex)

```
SELECT id from test_table WHERE json_value REGEXP 'field_4":"[^quality]*quality.*';
```

but return only id 1

I have readed many posts on internet but with no succes.
How should be the regex to get the proper rows?

**EDIT**
One more think, to be more explicit, first work from search is a full key from array, but the second is partial value, like a "%substring%"

Thank you

Comment: if you are on mysql 5.7 look into JSON_CONTAINS

Comment: i'm on Cpanel with Mysql 5.6.28

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I could come up with:

```
SELECT id from test_table WHERE json_value REGEXP 'field_4":"[^"]*quality';
```

It meets your requirements given the data you provided.  It will break, however, if your JSON contains embedded/escaped double-quotes, like:

```
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | json_value                                                                                                     |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"field_198":false,"field_4":"From quality office","field_9":"product with high quality","field_10":"comment"} |
|  2 | {"field_198":true,"field_4":"From ordering office","field_9":"back to quality office","field_10":"comment"}    |
|  3 | {"field_198":true,"field_4":"From ordering office","field_9":"cancelled","field_10":"comment"}                 |
|  4 | {"field_198":true,"field_4":"Return to quality office","field_9":"product ok","field_10":"comment"}            |
|  5 | {"field_198":true,"field_4":"Return to \"quality\" office","field_9":"product ok","field_10":"comment"}        |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id from test_table WHERE json_value REGEXP 'field_4":"[^"]*quality';
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  4 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

In this case I think you would have wanted the row with `id=5` to be returned, but it isn't.  But if you have that kind of data, I think you have no choice but to really parse it, and a regex won't do the trick.